# Can't access web page through mydomain.com/directory

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, cloudflare

I have a problem with I guess Cloudflare.I've just set up Cloudflare, and now I cant access my PHPBB3 installation through `http://www.mydomain.fake/forumas` but can through `http://www.mydomain.fake/forumas/index.php` .

When accessing `http://www.mydomain.fake/forumas` i get a 404 error.What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just have a `DirectoryIndex` directive at the top of your root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This will load `index.php` by default in any directory.